# How can a question net minus six votes but gain two reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

A recent question was posted by a user who had no other registered activity but had gained 2 reputation points. This would be possible if he had received (say) 4 up-votes and 9 down-votes, so that he had got negative 5 net votes. But in fact his net voting score was negative 6. I don't understand how this could have arisen.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not possible to go below 1 reputation. Hence if a new user posted a question, received 5 downvotes (reputation now 1), 1 upvote (reputation now 6), then 2 downvotes (reputation now 2) the situation you describe arises.

Comment: Thank you. This prompts another question, but I will post it separately.